# Facebook App Friend's Activity

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

What would be the correct way to retrieve a list of recent Actions/Objects for a particular app from the logged in user's friends or particular friend who also has the app installed?

Similar to how the Spotify app shows a feed on the right with all the logged in user's friend's actions e.g. "USER listened to X Song by Y Artist".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can retrieve the list of actions, if you know the namespace and action type of the app. This should be straightforward if it's your own app. If it's some other app, you need to figure out what they are using for the same.
There are similar questions here - 
[How to get activity from my app with Facebook Graph API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9814025/how-to-get-activity-from-my-app-with-facebook-graph-api) 
http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/7553714/read-custom-action-from-the-open-graph-beta 
There is more info here - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/actions/#read.